# Assign values to next digits

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I need to assign a values to the next digits. Code looks like below:

```
def numerujPoziomy():
    for i in range(0, liczbaPoziomow, 1):
        var = i + 1
        rootValue = 1
        y = rootValue
        print 'Level', var, 'value', y
```

Each next level has to be a half smaller than previous. Root has value 1, next level has value 0.5, next level has value o.25 etc. I don't know how to do this.

Result of my code:

```
Level 1 value 1
Level 2 value 1
Level 3 value 1
Level 4 value 1
Level 5 value 1
Level 6 value 1
```

But i need that result:

```
Level 1 value 1
Level 2 value 0.5
Level 3 value 0.25
Level 4 value 0.125
Level 5 value 0.0625
Level 6 value 0.03125
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `/ 2.0` in there somewhere, then? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO Seweryn! Remember that questions here should show both significant research (the answer shouldn't be readily available) and be applicable to other people (make the question as general as you can).

Comment: The expected result was useful, so I rolled back your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise 1/2 to the ith power.

```
liczbaPoziomow = 5

def numerujPoziomy():
    for i in range(0, liczbaPoziomow):
        print 'Level', i + 1, 'value',  0.5 ** i

numerujPoziomy()
>>> Level 1 value 1.0
>>> Level 2 value 0.5
>>> Level 3 value 0.25
>>> Level 4 value 0.125
>>> Level 5 value 0.0625
```

Comment: Your approach is faster

Comment: Thank you very much for that quick answer. Now life is easier :)

Answer (score 1):

You use the inverse of `2**i`:

```
def numerujPoziomy():
    for i in range(0, liczbaPoziomow, 1):
        print 'Level', i+1, 'value', 1./2**i
```

Note that in python 2.x it is **very** important that you have `1./2**i`, rather than `1/2**i`, because the latter will only return an integer, not a float like you want.  This problem is avoided in Python 3, or by using `from __future__ import division` at the beginning of your file.

Comment: "You use the inverse of `2**i`" which is of course `0.5 ** i`

Answer (score -2):

An easy way to do this is this:

```
def numerujPoziomy():
    rootValue = 1.0
    for i in range(0, liczbaPoziomow, 1):
        var = i + 1
        y = rootValue / 2
        rootValue = y
        print 'Level', var, 'value', y
```